# Checkbox binding to datagrid in wpf (mvvm)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am binding my data grid with a list of check boxes (WPF MVVM pattern).
In the UI, I am getting a check box list with an extra empty check box row.
And every time when I am checking that row and going back to any of the above options, automatically one more row is getting added.

I am attaching my code here.

Home.xaml HomeViewModel.cs

[image: HomeViewModel.cs]

Comment: It seems like DataGrid.CanUserAddRows property is set to true, change it to false and check.

Comment: yes..now it is working... :) thank you..

Comment: Please copy-paste the code rather than uploading an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this. It will solve your problem.

```
<DataGrid Name="UrGrid"
CanUserAddRows="False"
... >
```